# Reproducir video desde un servidor en iOS en unity 3D

Tags: ios, unity3d, video

Estoy tratando de reproducir video desde un servidor en iOS en unity 5.5.1, xcode 8.2.1, iOS 10.2.1

He tratado de las siguientes maneras:

1- con Easy Movie Texture, me sale el siguiente error
Use of undeclared indentifier 'GLES_CHK'
Incluyo la librería y sigue igual.

2- descargandolo con www, en android funciona perfecto pero en iOS sale esto en el log:

> ```
> (<OpenGL ES 2.0> ; Context handle 375690592
> Initialize engine version: 5.5.1f1 (88d00a7498cd)
> -------- Shader compilation failed), compila pero no reproduce y dice(WARNING: 0:4: 
> extension 'GL_EXT_frag_depth' is not supported
>
> ERROR: 0:38: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragDepthEXT'). You are using download 
> over http. Currently unity adds NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to Info.plist to simplify 
> transition, but it will be removed soon. Please consider updating to https.
> ```

Así que trate de configurar el info.plist como encontre en foros de stack overflow.

Que me recomiendan, puedo hacer la implementación descargando el video y luego reproduciendolo, o streaming.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo una Mac a la mano pero el plugin que comentas no me ha dado problemas hasta ahora, la parte de la inicializacipon de OpenGL  puede ser que estás usando Metal en lugar de OpenGl2, Unity ya debe soportar Metal para iOS pero, pot ahora yo sigo usando OpenGl2.

A veces el usar Metal genera problemas, Vuforia por ejemplo, pero no estoy del todo seguro si tiene el mismo efecto con Easy movie texture.

Puedes cambiarlo en Build Setings -> Player Setings -> Other setings y allí está la opción "Autographics API", si está seleccionada la deseleccionas y quitas Metal.

La alerta del infoplist respecto a la descarga puede ser ignorada por ahora sin embargo, y como dice el mensaje, dentro de poco vamos a tener que implementar todo con https.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, hice el procedimiento, pero sigue mostrandome esto cuando voy a hacer build en xcode:
`Use of undeclared  identifier GLES_CHK`